# I need to cut and paste a specific number of lines from a text document into another text document

Tags: python

I need to cut and paste an n number of lines from a text document into another one, i dont know what to use to delete the lines that i just copied.

```
x = 1
    while x == 1:
        copy = 2
        count = 0
        print ('test1=')
        x = 2

    with open("try3.txt") as f:
        with open("try4.txt", "a") as f1:
            for line in f:
                if count < 63:
                    count = count +1
                    print ('test2=')
                    f1.write(line)
                    f.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bCHQ.png)

Comment: Can you give us a sample of input and expected output?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a.txt

```
a
b
c
d
```

b.txt

code:

```py
a=open('a.txt','r').readlines()    #['a\n', 'b\n', 'c\n', 'd']
b=a[0:2]   #['a\n', 'b\n']
open('b.txt','w').writelines(b)    # write b to b.txt
for b_element in b:
    a.remove(b_element)    # remove b element in 'a' list
open('a.txt','w').writelines(a)    # write a to a.txt
```

result:

a.txt

```
c
d
```

b.txt

```
a
b
```